# youtube-ios-player-helper "play later button" not working

Tags: ios, youtube-api

Using the youtube-ios-player-helper library.  Very useful.  But I notice that the "play later" button does not work with the library.  When it's pressed it just changes to a "!".

It looks from the exposed methods, like that button is actually not part of the library but from the YouTube site so there's no way to control it.

Is that right?  Can you capture those methods or make it work when embedded in an iOS app somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the "watch later" button?

Comment: Yep.  That's the one.

Comment: I believe "watch later" is intended for you to sync with your account so you can watch videos later. I'm not sure that you can capture this information on an embedded video. Maybe you could file a feature request for it on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like not_a_bot is correct.  If there is no way to access the youtube account information the watch later button will not work.